# How would one implement a doAfterNext operator in Project Reactor?

Tags: project-reactor

RxJava2 has a `doAfterNext` operator that emits items downstream, and then invokes the consumer. It doesn't seem like Project Reactor has such an operator so I'd like to get some pointers on the best way to create my own to achieve the same thing.

The use case is freeing memory after the subscriber has received the item

Comment: To my knowledge there is no equivalent in reactor. But if you want to free resources you can look at doFinally. Another way to do it is to add doOnNext after the downstream element where you want to use the resource.

Comment: Unfortunately `doFinally` doesn't seem to handle `onNext`. Looking at `DoFinallySubscriber` the handler isn't called for `onNext`.

Comment: Also I need access to the object

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if leavering `doOnEach` is a valid solution:

```java
public class ByteBufferSafeReleaseConsumer implements Consumer<Signal<ByteBuffer<?>>> {

    private final List<ByteBuffer<?>> elements = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void accept(Signal<ByteBuffer<?>> signal) {
        if (signal.isOnNext()) {
            ByteBuffer<?> next = signal.get();
            if (next != null) {
                elements.add(next);
            }
        }
        if (signal.isOnComplete() || signal.isOnError()) {
            for (ByteBuffer<?> buffer : elements) {
                ByteBufferUtils.safeRelease(buffer);
            }
        }
    }
}

ByteBufferSafeReleaseConsumer consumer = new ByteBufferSafeReleaseConsumer()
Flux.from(byteBufferPublisher).doOnEach(consumer)
```

Comment: This requires not releasing the data until after all items are emitted which could lead to out of memory errors